# Best way to find determine friendship of users (FacebookSDK)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an iOS app which at one point displays a feed of information items to the user, that contain information about other users. These feed items are stored on a server that I run as well. I want to add a functionality that allows this user to filter the information and display only items of his facebook friends. It seems to me that there are three ways to achieve this

## 1

Client fetches all items.For each item run that FB SDK query /user-id/friends to determine friendship

## 2

Save all of the facebook ID's of the users friends on the client (each set time),and after fetching all items, determine if item is posted by friend with comparison to local database of friends.

## 3

The server with the feed items would run the query in the backend, and filter the content it provides to the client

Each of these has it's weakness and advantages, but I'd like to hear which is the preferred and "best" overall. I'm trying to achieve something like VENMO's home feed functionality if that makes sense.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: not sure what items you want to fetch exactly, but there are a lot of things to consider. you can only get the list of friends who authorized your app too, you can only get posts of the authorized user, read_stream will most likely not get approved, user tokens are not valid forever, .... better take a look at the changelog first: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: @luschn thats fine, and that is a scenario of which im describing. let's say there are 10,000 posts from 10k unique users, in which 10 of those users are my friend. You can thing of these items/posts as simple data which has two components "authorID" and "content", the "authorID" column/tag is the authors facebookID. What is the best way to fetch and display only posts of a users facebook friends.

Comment: you can´t fetch posts of the friends, as i said...